# Persisting java objects except cache or static

Tags: java, object, persistence

First of all sorry if the question is weird coz it seemed weird to me too. But still to confirm.

Are there any possible ways to persist a java object except using static specifier and cache?

Cache is not recommended since its an external source and static storage will take up a lot of memory.

Need something if so, with higher performance

Comment: In my understanding persist == save. Is your understanding different?
What are the requirements? How many, how long for, how frequent and fast is the access required? What did you mean by "static" persisting?

Answer (score 0):

Java object lifetime is not related to the keyword `static` (which means a different thing) or using a cache.

Since Java has a managed memory model, everything is managed by the [garbage collector](http://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garbage_collection), as long as an object is reachable (so it is referenced with a strong reference by another object which itself is reachable) then you don't have to worry about the risk of the deallocation of the object.